# Clarification on Deref coercion

Tags: rust

Consider this example:

```
fn main() {
    let string: String = "A string".to_string();
    let string_ref: &String = &string;
    let str_ref_a: &str = string_ref;  // A
    let str_ref_b: &str = &string;     // B
}
```

How exactly are lines *A* and *B* different? `string_ref` is of type `&String`, so my understanding is that in line *A* we have an example of *Deref coercion*. What about line *B* though? Is it correct to say that it has nothing to do with *Deref coercion* and we simply have "a direct borrowing of a `String` as `str`", due to this:

```
impl Borrow<str> for String {
    #[inline]
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self[..]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. Both lines involve deref coercion.

The `Borrow` trait is not special in any way - it is not known to the compiler (not a lang item). The `Deref` trait is.

The difference between `Deref` and `Borrow` (and also [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html)) is that `Deref` can only have one implementation for a type (since `Target` is an associated type and not a generic parameter) while `AsRef` (and `Borrow`) take a generic parameter and thus can be implemented multiple times. This is because `Deref` is for smart pointers: you should implement `Deref<Target = T>` if **I am a `T`** (note that the accurate definition of "smart pointer" is [in flux](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-are-smart-pointers/67361)). `String` **is** a `str` (plus additional features), and `Vec` **is** a slice. `Box<T>` **is** `T`.

On the other hand, `AsRef` and `Borrow` are conversion traits. I should implement `AsRef<T>` if **I can be viewed as** `T`. `String` can be viewed as `str`. But take e.g. `str` and `OsStr`. `str` is not an `OsStr`. But it can be treated like it if it was. So it [implements `AsRef<OsStr>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#impl-AsRef%3COsStr%3E-1). `Borrow` is the same as `AsRef` except it has additional requirements (namely, it should have the same `Eq`, `Hash` and `Ord` as the original value).

Comment: OK. But then what exactly is the purpose of having `impl Borrow<str> for String`? In what situations would its `borrow()` function be called? Is it correct to say that *deref coercion* in strings makes explicit calls to `string.borrow()` somewhat pointless?

Comment: @at54321 Added an explanation.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the `Target` in `Deref` trait can also be generic type (does not have to be concrete type). The [code sample in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-02-deref.html) shows the `Deref` implemeentation

Comment: @Ham Yes this is true, like any associated type.

Answer (score 1):

Both are essentially equivalent and involve deref coercion:

```
let str_ref_a: &str = string_ref;  // A
let str_ref_b: &str = &string;     // B
```

The value `string` above is of type `String`, so the expression `&string` is of type `&String` which coerces into `&str` due to *deref coercion* as `String` implements [`Deref<Target=str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref).

---

Regarding your question about `Borrow`: No, you aren't calling [`borrow()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#) on the `string` value. Instead, that would be:

```
let str_ref_b: &str = string.borrow(); // Borrow::borrow() on String
```

That is, unlike [`deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), the call to `borrow()` isn't inserted automatically.